# Convert three functions into a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is it possible to combine all the functions into a single function?  I'm providing [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hB2T8/) as well.

**I am trying to test it for different scenarios..
but I am not sure how to combine all the scenarios into one..**

```
var myNumbersToSort = [null, -1, 2, 0.001, -3, 4, 0.3,1,-0.0001];


function getClosestToZero(set) {
  if(0 === set.length) return null;
  var closest = set[0], result = 0;
  for(var i in set) {
     var next = set[i];
     if(Math.abs(closest) > Math.abs(next)) {
       result = i;
       closest = next;
     }
  }
  return closest;  
}

function getClosestToZeroWithNaN(set) {
    var closest;
    if(set instanceof Array) {
        for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            var val = set[i];
            if(!isNaN(val)){
                val = Number(val);
                var absVal = Math.abs(val);
                    if(typeof closest == 'undefined' || Math.abs(closest) > absVal)                       {
                    closest = val; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
function getClosestToZeroOnlyNumbers(set) {
    var closest;
    if(set instanceof Array) {
        for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
            var val = set[i];
            if(typeof val == "number"){
                var absVal = Math.abs(val);
                    if(typeof closest == 'undefined' || Math.abs(closest) > absVal)                       {
                    closest = val; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return closest;
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (getClosestToZeroOnlyNumbers(myNumbersToSort));
```

Comment: Keyword: **transducers**

Answer (score 3):

I think your code would be cleanest if you wrote the program as a composition of a minimum-absolute-value-of-array function and a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Assuming that performance in the face of large data sets is not a concern, you could have, for example:

```
function isNumber(val) {
    return typeof val == "number";
}

getClosestToZero(myNumbersToSort.filter(isNumber));
```

Alternatively, `getClosestToZero()` could directly support an optional second argument that servers as a filtering callback if it is provided.

Please pay attention to the consistency of the indentation.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hB2T8/  its confusing

Comment: According to our [help/on-topic] rules, asking for code to be written is off-topic for Code Review. The original question was marginal; your request would definitely violate our community's standards.